# Django check user.is_authenticated before UserCreationForm to prevent a user to signup twice

Tags: python, django

In Django, I am trying to prevent an already existing user to register (sign up) again. In my case, the user can sign up with a form. My approach is to check in `views.py` if the user already exists by checking `is_authenticated` upfront. If the user does not exist, then the form entries will be processed and the user will be created.

The problem: if the user already exists, I would expect the condition `request.user.is_authenticated` to be True and the browser to be redirected to home. Instead, the evaluation goes on to process the form throwing (of course) the following error:

Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(john.doe) already exists.

This is a sample of my `views.py`:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.error(request, ('User already exists.'))
            return redirect('home')
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ... # do more stuff
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**: But not sure if I should post this edit into Answer.

Meanwhile, I have found a working workaround by checking if the user exists in the `User` as an entry. This would go in the `form.is_valid()` block before working with the form data.

```
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']          
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or \
          User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.success(request, ('Error: user already exists.'))
        return redirect('auth:home')
```

Note that in this simplified example I am checking both on user name and email from the form entries:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
```

My own use case is a bit more complex because the user name is derived from the email and the email contains the company domain. This is why I was looking for some kind of a *shortcut*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `request.user.is_anonymous`?

Comment: Wether the user exists or not `requests.user.is_anonymous` is always true - I guess because not logged in yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is already logged in it will raise `is_authenticated` as True and False it there's no user logged in.

I guess you're trying to register/sign up with no active session, then the first inner if `request.user.is_authenticated` is evaluated False and not used, so it goes to the second inner if and then the database error is raised because you tried to use the same username.

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to register without active session. In fact, registration form is only available if the user is signed out. But what puzzles me is that wether the user exists already or not, `requests.user.is_authenticated` is always False.

Comment: Maybe you're not doing the expected use of is_authenticated. It just checks if there's an active user logged.
Actually, the database itself is doing the check for you and raises an error preventing the duplicate username. In my case, the form is re-rendered in the browser with all the others values and a warning message. In the console it appears the Exception Value as yours.

Comment: Right. Perhaps, I'm not using is_authenticated properly. The whole point though is to prevent the DB do the check for me and throw the error.